# Xcode produces "Segmentation fault: 11" compiling

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Compiling the following code, Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504) throws:
"error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'TestDel3' from project 'TestDel3')
"

If I comment out `Image(systemName: systemName)` and replace it with `Image(systemName: "person")` it compiles

```
struct ContentView: View{
  var body: some View {
    UseButtonContainer( b: ButtonContainer("x1",systemName:"person") {print("c1")})
  }
}

struct UseButtonContainer: View{
  let b : ButtonContainer
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      self.b.action();
      self.extraAction()
    }) { b.label}
  }

  func extraAction()->Void{
    print("extra action")
  }
}

struct ButtonContainer{
  let label: VStack<TupleView<(Image, Text)>>
  let action: ()-> Void

  init(_ text: String, systemName: String, action: @escaping ()-> Void){
    self.label = VStack{
      Image(systemName: systemName)     // Commenting out this line
      //Image(systemName: "person")     // and using this instead, it compiles
      Text(text)
    }
    self.action = action
  }
}

What's wrong here?
```

Comment: Image(systemName: systemName) - What do you think the "systemName"  value refers  here ? Do you want the default images or expecting "person" ?

Comment: I want the SF-Symbol named "person"

Comment: May be its a problem because the systemName in your init method has the name systemName and also Image's init method also has same name as the parameter names in init method are valid externally.

Comment: no, that's not the problem - I tested it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** the following variant works

```
struct ButtonContainer{
  let label: VStack<TupleView<(Image, Text)>>
  let action: ()-> Void

  init(_ text: String, systemName: String, action: @escaping ()-> Void){
    self.label = VStack {
      Image(systemName: "\(systemName)") // << make it string literal !!!
      Text(text)
    }
    self.action = action
  }
}
```

**Initial (just in case):**

Taking into account that SwiftUI uses almost everywhere opaque types by `some View`, the approach with erasing type for `label` compiled & run well (tested with Xcode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3). I'm not sure about your needs to have explicit type here, but just be aware.

```
struct ButtonContainer{
  let label: AnyView
  let action: ()-> Void

  init(_ text: String, systemName: String, action: @escaping ()-> Void){
    self.label = AnyView(VStack {
      Image(systemName: systemName)
      Text(text)
    })
    self.action = action
  }
}
```

Comment: Tnx @Asperi !, the fix compiles. Two questions: 1) was the original code "correct", do you know, why it did not compile? 2) Initially I did not follow the second approach, because I read, it could have a performance issue. Do you think, that's true?

Comment: @mica, 1) yes, code is correct and I think it's compiler bug (Xcode notes that itself and proposes submit a feedback); 2) no, that's not true, it is just type erasure, as any other such.